Do I need to repair a rotten joist?
While replacing the floor in our small toilet, I discovered that a joist (which is actually under the shower in the adjacent bathroom) has rotted away. The previous owners of the house had badly installed the shower tray, and I think it has been dripping onto the joist for about a decade.
Replacing the joist will not be easy, as it goes under the tiled bathroom floor. But I could probably get access to it by removing part of the ceiling in the room below. This is a Victorian terraced house in London, UK.
Here are some pictures of the joist. Since access to the joist is very restricted, the shots aren't too clear, but I've labelled the joist and the wall to help.
In this first image, you can see where the joist enters the exterior brick wall of the house. This is directly below the edge of the shower tray, and the top of the joist is visibly rotted away.

Looking further along the joist (beyond the left hand edge of this image) is almost impossible.
Zooming out, this outline shows approximately where the joist sits under the floor. This image also shows the hole in the floor behind the toilet (currently disconnected) where the previous photo was taken.

Question: How important is it to replace or repair this joist?

A picture or three of said joist and areas around it may be of use to provide a good answer.

Very important. Or, maybe not at all important. With the detail you've given us, that's about the best we can do for you.

Joists and the sub floor hold the weight above the floor.  So if it is where you walk or sit it is more important than a joist at an edge that does not have any weight except the floor.  It also matters how much of it is rotten.  An inch or two on a 2x10 is not as bad as 6 or 8 inches of rot.

@Triplefault - I will try to get a photo to show the joist. There's not much visibility.

Who uses the shower? little kids of 35 kg or me at 120kg...

@FreeMan - What details would help?

@SolarMike - The maximum weight of a person in our house is 70kg. But still, it would be nice to know if it's safe.

I can't discern anything from that photo. Sorry.

Is the joist under the wall and does the wall go all the way to the roof (assuming multi-storey)? Is the wall load-bearing? The answer probably does not matter anyway as joists are historically spaced too far apart to support loads and loose their strength as they age. Even w/o point loads, the floor will eventually deflect and result in progressive damage; tile cracking, wall cracking/sagging, issues w/door, etc.  Dynamic loads, like people in the shower, on the loo, will expedite damage from flexing. Suggest temporary bracing until you repair.

@isherwood - Sorry about the photo. It's very hard to get in there and take a bette photo. Is there something specific you'd like to know that maybe I could try to find out?

@IanW - The joist is a few inches beyond the back wall of the little bathroom, and about 2 foot beyond the wall of the main bathroom.
